# Saving paypal capture and custom order to database

Tags: node.js, mongoose, paypal

Im trying to save the Order with a payment property Payment._id but cant get the the capture id in the create route. Is there a way to pass some id through paypal and then get that ID in the capture? and is this a good idea to save the Order and Payment in the capture route?

The Payment Model stores the paypal capture

```js
router.post("/order/create", async (req, res) => {
  const { items, payment_method, price } = req.body;

  try {
    //Document just for validation that doesn't save
    const newOrder = new Order({
      items,
      payment_method,
      price,
    });

    const validationError = await newOrder.validate();
    if (validationError !== undefined) throw Error("Validation Failed");

    let request = new paypalSDK.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();

    const body = {
      intent: "CAPTURE",
      purchase_units: [
        {
          items: paypalItems(newOrder.items),
          amount: {
            currency_code: "USD",
            value: newOrder.price,
            breakdown: {
              item_total: {
                currency_code: "USD",
                value: newOrder.price,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ]
    };

    request.prefer("return=representation");
    request.requestBody(body);

    const order = await client.execute(request);

    res.status(200).json({
      orderID: order.result.id,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500);
  }
});

router.post("/order/capture", async (req, res) => {
  const { items, payment_method, price } = req.body;

  const orderID = req.body.orderID;

  const request = new paypalSDK.orders.OrdersCaptureRequest(orderID);
  request.requestBody({});

  try {
    const capture = await client.execute(request);
    const captureID = capture.result.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id;

    const newPayment = new Payment(capture.result);
    const savedPayment = await newPayment.save();

    const newOrder = new Order({
      items,
      payment_method,
      price,
      payment: savedPayment._id,
    });
    await newOrder.save();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.sendStatus(500);
  }
  res.status(200).json({});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `purchase_units[0]` of your [orders create request body](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body), you can include a unique** `invoice_id` (visible to the payer, indexed for searching), or an arbitrary `custom_id` (only visible to the receiver, not indexed).

**The invoice ID should never have been used before for a successfully captured payment, or this will result in a Duplicate Invoice ID error in the default configuration (to prevent accidental duplicate payments for the same thing)*

---

When you capture an order successfully, the PayPal transaction ID will be at `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`. Store this in your database for future reference.